# How to get an older library from Maven using Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I need to have an older Maven library of *eclipselink* using Android Studio 1.2.

When I use the Library Dependency to search for *eclipselink*, I get the following results:

[image]

However, this library was compiled using Java 8, so it is not suitable for me.

This is my *gradle.build* file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'org.odata4j:odata4j-dist:0.7.0'
    provided 'org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

If I change the *org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.6.0* to *org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.1.2*, I get this error:

> Failed to resolve: org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.1.2

How could I use an older version of this library?

UPDATE:

I've tried to use v2.4.2 but it couldn't compile, so I downloaded a 2.1.2 jar and added as a file dependency. Now it can't find it, and searches in the SDK library. This Maven/Gradle thing is very, very far from NuGet...

This is the gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/eclipselink-2.1.2.jar')
    compile 'org.odata4j:odata4j-dist:0.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'

}
```

And the message:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.1.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.1.2/eclipselink-2.1.2.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.1.2/eclipselink-2.1.2.jar
         file:/C:/Users/Nestor/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.1.2/eclipselink-2.1.2.pom
         file:/C:/Users/Nestor/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.1.2/eclipselink-2.1.2.jar
         file:/C:/Users/Nestor/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.1.2/eclipselink-2.1.2.pom
         file:/C:/Users/Nestor/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.1.2/eclipselink-2.1.2.jar
     Required by:
         MyApp:app:unspecified > org.odata4j:odata4j-dist:0.7.0 > org.odata4j:odata4j-core:0.7.0
```

It just simply ignores the gradle file.

UPDATE #2:

I copied the jar to the SDK library. When I build now, I get this error:

```
:app:preDexDebug
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
trouble processing "javax/xml/stream/EventFilter.class":
Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.
However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.
If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.
If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the solution is ***not to use Gradle*** in the project and use the old fashioned (and working) way: **add the jars manually**. This is the reliable way.

Answer (score 2):

Search dependencies on [bintray](https://bintray.com/), e.g. [this](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/org.eclipse.persistence%3Aeclipselink/view) is what I get when searching for 'eclipselink'. Indeed, there's no 2.1.2 version, so you'll have to pick one from the list.

Answer (score 1):

The earliest version of org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink is 2.4.2 http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink

Or you could try to download an older .jar manually somehow